# SparkUI is stopping after execution of code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am trying to perform this simple Spark job using IntelliJ IDEA in Scala. However, Spark UI stops completely after complete execution of the object. Is there something that I am missing or listening at wrong location? Scala Version - 2.10.4 and Spark - 1.6.0

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
    object SimpleApp {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val logFile = "C:/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
        val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
        val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
        println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
      }
    }

16/02/24 01:24:39 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/02/24 01:24:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: Sivaram Konanki
16/02/24 01:24:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: Sivaram Konanki
16/02/24 01:24:40 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(Sivaram Konanki); users with modify permissions: Set(Sivaram Konanki)
16/02/24 01:24:41 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 54881.
16/02/24 01:24:41 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.1.15:54894]
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 54894.
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\Sivaram Konanki\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-dad99e77-f3a6-4a1d-88d8-3b030be0bd0a
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2.4 GB
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.1.15:4040
16/02/24 01:24:42 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/02/24 01:24:43 INFO Utils: <b>Successfully started service
'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54913.
16/02/24 01:24:43 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 54913
16/02/24 01:24:43 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/02/24 01:24:43 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:54913 with 2.4 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 54913)
16/02/24 01:24:43 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/02/24 01:24:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 127.4 KB, free 127.4 KB)
16/02/24 01:24:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 13.9 KB, free 141.3 KB)
16/02/24 01:24:44 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:54913 (size: 13.9 KB, free: 2.4 GB)
16/02/24 01:24:44 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at SimpleApp.scala:11
16/02/24 01:24:45 WARN : Your hostname, OSG-E5450-42 resolves to a loopback/non-reachable address: fe80:0:0:0:d9ff:4f93:5643:703d%wlan3, but we couldn't find any external IP address!
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at SimpleApp.scala:12
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (count at SimpleApp.scala:12) with 2 output partitions
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (count at SimpleApp.scala:12)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at SimpleApp.scala:12), which has no missing parents
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.1 KB, free 144.5 KB)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1886.0 B, free 146.3 KB)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:54913 (size: 1886.0 B, free: 2.4 GB)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at SimpleApp.scala:12)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2172 bytes)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2172 bytes)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_1_1 not found, computing it
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_1_0 not found, computing it
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/C:/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/README.md:1679+1680
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/C:/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/README.md:0+1679
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_1_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 4.7 KB, free 151.0 KB)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_1 in memory on localhost:54913 (size: 4.7 KB, free: 2.4 GB)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_1_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.4 KB, free 156.5 KB)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_0 in memory on localhost:54913 (size: 5.4 KB, free: 2.4 GB)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 2662 bytes result sent to driver
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 2662 bytes result sent to driver
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 170 ms on localhost (1/2)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 143 ms on localhost (2/2)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (count at SimpleApp.scala:12) finished in 0.187 s
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: count at SimpleApp.scala:12, took 0.303861 s
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at SimpleApp.scala:13
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (count at SimpleApp.scala:13) with 2 output partitions
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (count at SimpleApp.scala:13)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at SimpleApp.scala:13), which has no missing parents
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.1 KB, free 159.6 KB)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1888.0 B, free 161.5 KB)16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on localhost:54913 (size: 1888.0 B, free: 2.4 GB)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at SimpleApp.scala:13)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 2 tasks
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2172 bytes)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, localhost, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2172 bytes)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_1_0 locally
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_1_1 locally
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2). 2082 bytes result sent to driver
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3). 2082 bytes result sent to driver
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) in 34 ms on localhost (1/2)
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) in 37 ms on localhost (2/2)
Lines with a: 58, Lines with b: 26
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (count at SimpleApp.scala:13) finished in 0.040 s
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: count at SimpleApp.scala:13, took 0.068350 s
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.15:4040
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/02/24 01:24:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\Sivaram Konanki\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-861b5aef-6732-45e4-a4f4-6769370c555e
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a

`Thread.sleep(1000000);//For 1000 seconds or more`

at the bottom of your spark job, this will allow you to inspect the WebUI in IDEs like IntelliJ while running your Spark Job.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior. Spark UI is maintained by the `SparkContext` so it cannot be active after application finished and context has been destroyed.

In the standalone mode information is preserved by the cluster web UI, on Mesos or Yarn you can use history server but in the local mode the only option I am aware of is to keep application running.

Comment: Then how can we check Spark UI for jobs information? Is there any way to check once spark UI terminates?

Comment: @Nishan In local mode? It is not possible. Otherwise see [Viewing After the Fact](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact)

Comment: Hi @zero323 thanks for reply. Looks like it is Linux cmd, Can you please let me know how can get the same thing in windows os ?

Comment: @Nishan I don't think running cluster on Windows is even partially supported but I could be wrong. Haven't used Windows in years